# after clicking on tab I want show this alert only once ? bt it showing me multiple times?

Tags: javascript

I want to show alert only once after clicking

```
<div class="alert_box">
    <div class="cjtd_party_busy_alert dialog" title="">

        <span class="close_btn_s">X</span>
        <h3>Alert!</h3>
        <h4>
            <div>
                @if (busyParties.Count == 1)
                {
                    <span>@busyParties.FirstOrDefault() </span>
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var party in busyParties)
                    {
                        <span>@party </span>
                        if (!party.Equals(busyParties.Last(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            <span>,</span>
                        }
                    }
                }
                may be engaged in another appointment.
                <br /><br />
                For details, perform queue search.
            </div>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What alert? I can't see it in your code...

Comment: You need to show us the code (JavaScript) that shows this box otherwise there is nothing we can do